# ruby variable as same object (pointers?)

Tags: ruby, variables, pointers

```
>> a = 5
=> 5
>> b = a
=> 5
>> b = 4
=> 4
>> a
=> 5
```

how can I set 'b' to actually be 'a' so that in the example, the variable a will become four as well. thanks.

Comment: Sounds like pointers... Not a Ruby dev, but I don't think pointers are in Ruby.

Comment: Yes there are pointers in Ruby. They are references to the variables created by their class types. Here b was pointing to where a is until it made a new pointer for itself referencing Fixnum 4.

Comment: The answer shows that = assignment creates these pointers and when types of the same are pointing to the same reference all that's necessary is to change the reference object and both same types have equal object reference. Keep in mind why they say "In Ruby, everything is an Object." Lots of truth in that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class Ref
  def initialize val
    @val = val
  end

  attr_accessor :val

  def to_s
    @val.to_s
  end
end

a = Ref.new(4)
b = a

puts a   #=> 4
puts b   #=> 4

a.val = 5

puts a   #=> 5
puts b   #=> 5
```

When you do `b = a`, `b` points to the same object as `a` (they have the same `object_id`).

When you do `a = some_other_thing`, a will point to another object, while `b` remains unchanged.

For `Fixnum`, `nil`, `true` and `false`, you cannot change the value without changing the `object_id`. However, you can change other objects (strings, arrays, hashes, etc.) without changing `object_id`, *since you don't use the assignment (`=`)*.

Example with strings:

```
a = 'abcd'
b = a

puts a  #=> abcd
puts b  #=> abcd

a.upcase!          # changing a

puts a  #=> ABCD
puts b  #=> ABCD

a = a.downcase     # assigning a

puts a  #=> abcd
puts b  #=> ABCD
```

Example with arrays:

```
a = [1]
b = a

p a  #=> [1]
p b  #=> [1]

a << 2            # changing a

p a  #=> [1, 2]
p b  #=> [1, 2]

a += [3]          # assigning a

p a  #=> [1, 2, 3]
p b  #=> [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.**  Variables hold references to values, not references to other variables.

Here's what your example code is doing:

```
a = 5 # Assign the value 5 to the variable named "a".
b = a # Assign the value in the variable "a" (5) to the variable "b".
b = 4 # Assign the value 4 to the variable named "b".
a # Retrieve the value stored in the variable named "a" (5).
```

See this article for a more in-depth discussion of the topic: [*pass by reference or pass by value*](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/41160).

Comment: There is no way to do this? At all? Even with some kludge? No value that can represent the reference? I have been finding that I can do all kinds of crazy things in ruby fairly easily, I am surprised that this is not possible. Thanks for your response. I want to basically hide the real variable, could I adapt the set method of the variable to also set the other variable? Would this incur much overhead?

Comment: Nope, not using the syntax in your example.  You could do some fancy tricks with `eval` to write functions that load/store the values in other variables but that's about it.  See this [discussion of Ruby pass by reference vs value](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/41160).

Comment: This is wrong! b = a most emphatically does NOT assign 5 to b because 5 is the value in a. The value in a is a reference to a fixnum. b=a assigns that reference to b.

Answer (score 1):

As has been noted the syntax you are using can not be done. Just throwing this out there though you could make a wrapper class it depends what you actually want to do

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :007 > class Wrapper
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :008?>   attr_accessor :number
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :009?>   def initialize(number)
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :010?>     @number = number
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :011?>   end
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :012?> end
 => nil 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :013 > a = Wrapper.new(4)
 => #<Wrapper:0x100336db8 @number=4> 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :014 > b = a
 => #<Wrapper:0x100336db8 @number=4> 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :015 > a.number = 6
 => 6 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :016 > a
 => #<Wrapper:0x100336db8 @number=6> 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :017 > b
 => #<Wrapper:0x100336db8 @number=6>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays:

```
a = [5]
b = a
b[0] = 4
puts a[0]  #=>  4
```

This idea is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210411/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-a-reference-to-a-variable-in-ruby/5210673#5210673).

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of reference.

```
>> a = 5
=> 5
>> a.object_id
=> 11
>> b = a
=> 5
>> b.object_id
=> 11
>> b = 4
=> 4
>> b.object_id
=> 9
>> a.object_id
=> 11
# We did change the Fixnum b Object.
>> Fixnum.superclass
=> Integer
>> Integer.superclass
=> Numeric
>> Numeric.superclass
=> Object
>> Object.superclass
=> BasicObject
>> BasicObject.superclass
=> nil
```

I hope this gives us all a little better understanding about objects in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

One option in cases where you feel you would like to have direct pointer operations is to use the replace method of Hashes, Arrays & Strings.

this is useful for when you would like to have a method return a variable that a proc the method sets up will change at a later date, and don't want the annoyance of using a wrapper object.

example:

```
def hash_that_will_change_later
  params = {}
  some_resource.on_change do
    params.replace {i: 'got changed'}
  end
  params
end
a = hash_that_will_change_later
=> {}
some_resource.trigger_change!
a
{i: 'got changed'}
```

It's probably better generally to use explicit object wrappers for such cases, but this pattern is useful for building specs/tests of asynchronous stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Ruby expert.  But for a technically crazy kluge...that would only work if you felt like going through `eval` every time you worked with a variable:

```
>> a = 5
=> 5
>> b = :a
=> :a
>> eval "#{b} = 4"
=> 4
>> eval "#{a}"
=> 4
>> eval "#{b}"
=> 4
```

Note that a direct usage of `b` will still give you `:a` and you can't use it in expressions that aren't in `eval`:

```
>> b
=> :a
>> b + 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for :a:Symbol
```

...and there are certainly a ton of caveats.  Such as that you'd have to capture the `binding` and pass it around in more complex scenarios...

['pass parameter by reference' in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161510/pass-parameter-by-reference-in-ruby)

@Paul.s has an answer for if you can change the point of declaration to be a wrapper object, but if you can only control the point of reference then here's a `BasicReference` class I tried:

```
class BasicReference
    def initialize(r,b)
        @r = r
        @b = b
        @val = eval "#{@r}", @b
    end

    def val=(rhs)
        @val = eval "#{@r} = #{rhs}", @b
    end

    def val
        @val
    end
end

a = 5

puts "Before basic reference"
puts "   the value of a is #{a}"

b = BasicReference.new(:a, binding)

b.val = 4

puts "After b.val = 4"
puts "   the value of a is #{a}"
puts "   the value of b.val is #{b.val}"
```

This outputs:

```
Before basic reference
   the value of a is 5
After b.val = 4
   the value of a is 4
   the value of b.val is 4
```