# There's some way to reuse string?

Tags: ruby

In case,

```
A = "A"
B = "#{A}"
```

It's `B = "A"`, right?

And now I would like to change (`A = "C"`) and want `B` to change by effect of `A` too.

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169277/ruby-variable-as-same-object-pointers

Comment: the string is already interpreted and will not change after that.
what is the exact use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's talk about naming conventions first. Uppercase identifiers are used for constants in Ruby. Per default assigning a new value to an already initialized constant raises a warning in Ruby:

```
A = 'B'
A = 'C'
#=> warning: already initialized constant A
#=> warning: previous definition of A was here
```

Therefore I will use normal instance variables and reader methods in the following example. As Pascal Betz already pointed out: If you want `b` to depend on the current value of `a` then `b` should be a method:

```
def b
  @a
end

@a = 'A'
b
#=> "A"

@a = 'C'
b
#=> "C"
```

Comment: I just provided reason, but you demonstrated! +1

Answer (score 2):

If you do this:

```
a = "A"
b = "#{a}"
```

`a` and `b` are strings with the same content, but they're not the same objects:

```
b == a
# => true
b.equal? a
# => false
a.object_id
# => 24494240
b.object_id
# => 24679880
```

Ruby strings are mutable. So if `b` and `a` refer to the same string, modifying `a` will automatically update `b` too:

```
a = "A"
# => "A" 
b = a
# => "A" 
a.replace 'C'
# => "C" 
b
# => "C"
```

It works in both directions:

```
b.gsub!('C', 'D')
# => "D" 
a
# => "D"
```